# Documentation changes which don't completely handle improvement requests

Tags: discussion, documentation, review-queues

For example, let's have a look at the following documentation proposed change: https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/review/changes/134749

The change is valid, however does not entirely handle improvement requests.

> Handles improvement requests:
>
> This example is completely unclear, incomplete, or has severe formatting problems. It is unlikely to be salvageable through editing
>   and should be removed. –  Seth C. Mar 14 at 4:08
>
> no relevance or explanation, uses anonymous functions as a sample -> bad for teaching development though examples

What should one vote? If I approve, the improvement request will be closed and the example is less likely to be improved further. If I decline, at the end I'm declining a useful improvement (even if minor).

Thanks.

Comment: How about approve and then create a new improvement request yourself?

Comment: The change was approved, so I re-added the improvement request as you suggested. I can see this resulting in a loop of unnecessary requests though.

Comment: Perhaps an option "unlink from improvement request then approve" would be useful?